# Sub Query Problems

Tags: php, mysql, geo

Im having issues getting my head around how i go about coding the following. I have one table with a list of lat/longitudes and another table with a list of place names with latitudes and longitudes. What i need to do is this : 
1) Loop through each item in table 1, grab the lat and long, do a radius search on table 2 and grab the place name, update table 1 with the new place name. This code gets me the place name i require :

```
$sql="SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos(radians('".$lat."')) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos( radians(lon) - radians('".$lng."')) + sin(radians('".$lat."')) * 
sin(radians(lat)))) 
AS distance 
FROM cats HAVING distance < 5 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1";
```

I need help figuring out how i join the 2 queries together, or the best way for me to loop through lat/longs from table 1. I tried doing this with a php loop but i dont think thats the best way and i couldn't get it to work

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your description I think that you need something like this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET place_name = (SELECT place_name FROM 
table2
WHERE (3959 * acos(cos(radians('".$lat."')) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos( radians(lon) - radians('".$lng."')) + sin(radians('".$lat."')) * 
sin(radians(lat)))) < 5
ORDER BY (3959 * acos(cos(radians('".$lat."')) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos( radians(lon) - radians('".$lng."')) + sin(radians('".$lat."')) * 
sin(radians(lat)))) DESC
LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Just a note for anyone stumbling across this answer, the lat/long are not variables but need to be changed to references in the tables. ( table_2.lon etc )